# can we assign width to li

Tags: html, css

i have following html page with UL and LI, i try to assign width to each LI but can't see cay success

```
   <html>
   <head>
   <style type="text/css"> 

   ul
   { 
      overflow-x:hidden;
     white-space:nowrap; 
     height: 1em;
      width: 100%;
     } 

     li
  { 
    display:inline;
     padding-right:10px;
      }       
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <ul> 
        <li style="width:100px">abcdefghijklmonpqrstuvwxyz</li> 
      <li>abcdefghijklmonpqrstuvwxyz</li> 
   <li>abcdefghijklmonpqrstuvwxyz</li> 
   <li>abcdefghijklmonpqrstuvwxyz</li> 
    <li>abcdefghijklmonpqrstuvwxyz</li> 
     <li>abcdefghijklmonpqrstuvwxyz</li> 
      <li>abcdefghijklmonpqrstuvwxyz</li> 
    </ul> 

    </body>
   </html>
```

because each of my LI has different width.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you can't assign width to anything that is displayed inline, which you've set your `LI` to be. Instead, you most often want to use `display: block; float: left;` which'll allow for setting width.

Answer (score 24):

Try to replace your `display:inline` by `display:inline-block`

Comment: this will do the trick, unless you're concerned with keeping your code XHTML compliant. inline-block is not supported completely cross browser: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#t03

Comment: +1 This should be the way to do what OP wants. But IE (6 and 7?) will only apply `display: inline-block;` to elements that are naturally inline (`span`, as an example), so one has to be careful with inline-block for pages that are meant to be compatible with *outdated* browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this CSS

```
ul {
 white-space: nowrap;
 height: 1em;
 width: 100%;
}

li {
 list-style-type: none;
 width: 100px;
 overflow-x: auto; /* change to hidden if that's what you want */
 float: left;
 margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are giving the `li`s `display: inline` and `width`doesn't apply to inline elements. You'll need to use an alternative to position the elements beside each other such as floating them.

Answer (score 0):

To provide more on the previous two answers, you can't specify the width inline, but you can check out an example on how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257505/css-fixed-width-in-a-span)

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to work on your code because you can't assign widths to inline elements. But this can be solved by setting the display to block and by floating it.