# Increase span width not with text width - CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to increase the width of #Item, but it increases only with text width.

**HTML**

```
<div><span class="Item">Brand Strategy:</span><span class="Summary">Strategy</span></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.Item{background-color:#000; height:40px; color:#FFF; text-align:center; width:200px;}
```

How do I get the specified width for #Item.

Thanks
Jean

Comment: Somebody correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think spans are allowed to have a fixed width. It can have a right margin or padding though, if you're trying to put some space between spans.

Comment: @kijin spans cant have widths?

Comment: Apparently, inline elements can't have widths. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257505/css-fixed-width-in-a-span

Comment: @kijin not looking to set width for text, but for span.  If you could put this as an answer too

Answer (score 10):

I wrote part of this in comments above, but rewriting here for further clarification.

`<span>` is an inline element. Inline elements can't have a fixed width; their width is determined by the width of the text they contain, plus the margins and paddings.

See [CSS fixed width in a span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257505/css-fixed-width-in-a-span)

You can change this behavior by turning your span into a block-level element. This is done by setting `display: block` or `display: inline-block`. But this also introduces other behavior, such as floating and taking up a whole line instead of staying inside the paragraph. This, again, can be countered by `float: left` and similar options. Weigh the different options and decide based on your needs.

In your specific code example, you might benefit from using `<dt>` and `<dd>` tags instead. They were built for exactly that purpose.

Comment: I wanted to upvote what you have written, and possible provide you with a accept if the solution works

Answer (score 1):

The `span` is [inline element](http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/qt/block_vs_inline_elements.htm), you can not apply width or height to it unless you make it [block-level element](http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/qt/block_vs_inline_elements.htm) like this:

```
span.Item{
   display:block;
   background-color:#000;
   height:40px;
   color:#FFF;
   text-align:center;
   width:200px;
}
```

Or you can set the `display` to `inline-block` to support old dumb IE versions.

**More Info:**

- [Block-Level vs. Inline Elements](http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/qt/block_vs_inline_elements.htm)

Alternatively, you can use a `div` to apply the width if you want.

Comment: Hey sarfraz,long time no see.

Comment: @Jean: Yeah, have been very busy at office as well as home :)

Comment: I did the span with a block, width is applied but not w.r.t 200px, something by default.  But when .Item is added the css does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: inline-block` , if you use `display: block` you will have to `float: left` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The span is an inline element, so the only way to change its width is to make it a block element or setting its display to inline-block. After doing this, you should float it to the left.

I hope this was of help.

Answer (score -2):

The `<span>` element in an inline element. Therefore,  you cannot apply `width` or `height`.

Comment: wrong answer, you can apply width/height if you set display property (block for example)

Comment: @EugeneMihaylin Just a heads up: Don't flag posts as "Low Quality" because of technical inaccuracies.