# CSS fixed width in span

Tags: html, css

There was an example of fixed span i need: [CSS fixed width in a span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257505/css-fixed-width-in-a-span)

Quote:

```
<li><span></span> The lazy dog.</li>
<li><span>AND</span> The lazy cat.</li>
<li><span>OR</span> The active goldfish.</li>
```

and the author wanted:

```
    The lazy dog.
AND The lazy cat.
OR  The active goldfish.
```

But if i have long left part:

```
                 The lazy dog.
ANDDDDDDDDDDDDDD The lazy cat.
OR               The active goldfish.
```

But i really need:

```
                 The lazy dog.
ANDDDDDDDDDDDDDD The lazy cat.
              OR The active goldfish.
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Oh, sorry... text-align: right looks like what i need.

Comment: I think you sould delete the question as this isn't a common problem which will help others and you have your solution.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this would work for you
Try to imitate table display

```
li{
   display:table-row;        
}
li span{
   display:table-cell;
   text-align:right;
   padding-right:5px;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/unloco/3kjfz/2/)