# CSS fixed width li with fixed span

Tags: html, css

I've wrote problem here: [CSS fixed width in span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148108/css-fixed-width-in-span)

and that had solution just with 'text-align:right;'. But now:

```
                 The lazy dog.
ANDDDDDDDDDDDDDD The lazy cat.
              OR The active goldfish.
```

if i have long right part:

```
                 The lazy dog.
ANDDDDDDDDDDDDDD The lazy cat lazy cat lazy cat lazy cat
very lazy cat lazy cat very.
              OR The active goldfish.
```

And this is really problem, bcz i need:

```
                 The lazy dog.
ANDDDDDDDDDDDDDD The lazy cat lazy cat lazy cat lazy cat
                 very lazy cat lazy cat very.
              OR The active goldfish.
```

So, is it possible with span & ul-li ?

Here is example: http://jsfiddle.net/gBdMf/

Comment: It will be much easier to help if you provide a working example on JSFiddle or sth like that.

Comment: Why are you using `<li>`s and `<span>`s? Is there a reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a DEFINITION LIST instead of an unordered list.

See: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/format-dl/

And: http://www.css-101.org/articles/glossary-and-table-format/definition-list.php