# How to set fixed width for span

Tags: html, css

see my screenshot, even I set width, the span width still be "auto"

[image]

here is my

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row"><span style="width:60px;background-color: red;">prefix1</span><span>prpr</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row"><span style="width:60px;background-color: red;">pre2</span><span>prpr</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS fixed width in a span](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257505/css-fixed-width-in-a-span)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Set the display property of the spans to inline-block like:

```css
.container span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row"><span style="width:60px;background-color: red;">prefix1</span><span>prpr</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row"><span style="width:60px;background-color: red;">pre2</span><span>prpr</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

An inline element occupies only the space bounded by the tags that define the inline element ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements)).

Comment: That's just the way inline elements are designed to work. You can get more details at the link I posted in my answer as well as at https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-width

Comment: thank you, more on `inline-block` at the excellent CSS-Tricks site: https://css-tricks.com/when-do-you-use-inline-block/

Answer (score -1):

```
 Just use 

<div class="container">
<div class="row" style="width:auto;background-color: red;"><span>prefix1</span><span>prpr</span></div>
<div class="row" style="width:auto;background-color: red;"><span>pre2</span><span>prpr</span></div>
</div>
```