# Not able to change span height and width inside image tag

Tags: html, css

I have referred this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257505/css-fixed-width-in-a-span) but it dint help me out . I am trying to change span tags **height and width** inside image tag but it's not working and this is my code:

**html**

```
<img class="profile_pic" alt="Sumanth Jois" src="file/someimage">
           <span  class="changePicture">HelloThere</span>     
 </img>
```

**Css**

```
     //There are many spans so I am using the . operator to specify
     span.changePicture{
        width: 100px;
       height:200px;
       background-color:red;
        margin-left: -150px;
        color: white;
        margin-top: -20px;
     }
```

I am not able to change the width and height using this code.Can I know how I can solve this?

ThankYou

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does height and width not apply to span?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491068/does-height-and-width-not-apply-to-span)

Comment: `</img>` ? must be like this `<img class="profile_pic" alt="Sumanth Jois" src="file/someimage" />` you can't add html inside it

Comment: The browser won't nest the `span` inside the `img`, because an `img` cannot be a parent. The browser will place it below the `img` instead, and ignore/delete the `</img>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `span` is a single line element. So no `height`.

Second, **image is not** : `<img> </img>`

Image tag is a single tag `<img />`

**Try using a `div` instead of the `span`.**   And may be add `span` within it.

`span` is by default an inline element which cannot take width and height properties but you may use `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` to set height/width to it.

Snippet to overlay  span over image :

```css
div {
  top: 10px;
  left: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" alt="image" />

<div>
  <H1>Text </H1>
</div>
```

Comment: ThankYou but i want to overlay div  tag over Image tag how can i do that

Answer (score 1):

First of all the way you use img tag was wrong the html must be like this:

```
<img class="profile_pic" alt="Sumanth Jois" src="file/someimage" />
           <span  class="changePicture">HelloThere</span>
```

and just add `display:block;` to css to set height and width

```
 span.changePicture{
        width: 100px;
       height:200px;
       background-color:red;
        margin-left: -150px;
        color: white;
        margin-top: -20px;
        display:block; /*added*/
     }
```

EDITED:

To do that you need to put the image into div like this one:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="background-img">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT_1tKSY61_ZLpmpR0PWO784otZulHIMgrNLECJ-Te8HwvqoXMJZv8GYDo" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                  <div class="overlay">
                  <span>Text</span>
                  </div>
     </div>            
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
.background-img .overlay{
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.background-img .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 51, 51, 0.5);
}
.container{position:relative;
  max-width:300px;
  }

.container img{width:100%;
display:block;
 }
```

Here is the jsfiddle:
[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/52ms14gf/5/)

Comment: Thankyou it works but i want span to visible on image which is not happening

Comment: you want to overlay the span to image?

Comment: yep exactly how can i do that